# MySQL Update 'n' number of rows with new info by row[id]?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, arrays

Ok, i have a collection of php files that serve as a web based inventory system. After searching for an item and choosing one from a list, the user is taken to a page that displays the Present quantity for the previously selected items. On that same page, javascript is used to either add or subtract from the present quantity value. I would like to be able to take the updated values in the Present Quantity texboxes, and update them in MySQL.

Note that the number of items displayed varies by the amount selected on the search page.

The following is the update page, where the user can add or subtract from the quantity value:

```
<html>
<title>Update Selections</title>
<body>
<?php
    include("menu.php");
    include("sqlconnect.php");


?>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

function add(obj,ud){
 while (obj.parentNode){
  if (obj.nodeName.toUpperCase()=='TR'){
   obj=obj.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0];
   break;
  }
  obj=obj.parentNode;
 }
 if (obj.nodeName.toUpperCase()=='INPUT'){
  obj.value=Math.max(obj.value*1+ud,0);
 }
}


/*]]>*/
</script></head>


<p align="center"><b>Make Updates:</b>
<br />
<br />
The following items were selected for quantity update:
<br />
<br />
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Item:</th>
<th>QUANTITY</th>
<th>ADD/SUBTRACT</th></tr>
<style>
textarea {resize: none;}
</style>
<form action="updatequantityprocess.php" method="post">
<?php

        //$row_id = $_POST['itemselect'];
        foreach ($_POST['itemselect'] as $confirm)
        {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id='$confirm'");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Item'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td bgcolor='grey'><input type='text' id='value' name='itemupdate[]' disabled='disabled' style='text-align: center' value='" . $row['QuaninInventory'] . "'><input type='hidden' value='" . $row['id'] . "' name='itemid[]'></td>";
                echo "<td><div align='center'><input type='button' value='+' onclick='add(this, 1)'><input type='button' value='-' onclick='add(this, -1)'></div></td></tr>";

            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
?>
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Update">
<br />
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="<-- Back to Results" ONCLICK="window.location.href='http://localhost/Inventory/quantitybybrandprocess.php'">
</p>
</form>
</body>     
</html>
```

I have no idea how to construct the next page, `quantityupdateprocess.php`, using the `itemupdate[]` and `item[]` arrays to update the selected items in the MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all of the itemid's with a foreach loop and update each one individually.

```
foreach($_POST["itemids"] as $itemid){
    //Do mysql update based on other fields (make sure to escape itemid, and the other fields as well, or even better use prepared statements).
}
```

In order to access the quantity of the current item, do something like this.

```
foreach($_POST["itemids"] as $i=>$itemid){
    //do mysql updates where $_POST["itemupdate"][$i] is the item update for the item id.
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I also need to update the new quantity of each selected item. So I have 2 $_POST arrays, one with the id of the selected rows, and the other with the new values the user entered. I dont think that your code does that. I know i need to use a foreach loop to loop through the id's, but then I have to update the quantity for each id from the $_POST['itemupdate'] array.

Answer (score 0):

I'll present it with a simplier approach based on your question's title:

First of all, the `mysql` extensions use is highly discouraged, instead use [**PHP PDO**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Example:

```
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=http://yourhost.com;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$STH = $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO `yourtable` (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES (?, ?)');

foreach($array as $value) {
    $STH->bindParam(1, $value);
    $STH->bindParam(2, $value);
    $STH->execute();
}

$DBH = null;
```

You can use `prepared statements` which automatically escape all invalid or problematic characters. You can also make a prepared statement and reuse it to insert large series of data while it optimizes the whole process.

You can find more information on [**phpro.org's PDO tutorial pages**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). They are pretty well explained.

And regarding your question, in this case you may have to implement something like this:

Let's say that you receive an array of the form `id => values[]` through the `$_POST`, so your query would look like this:

```
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=http://yourhost.com;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$STH = $DBH->prepare('UPDATE `yourtable` SET `column1` = ?, `column2` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');

foreach($array as $id => $values) {
    $STH->bindParam(1, $values[0]);
    $STH->bindParam(2, $values[1]);
    $STH->bindParam(3, $id);
    $STH->execute();
}
```